# Comparison of Direct Methods to solve Linear System in terms of flop count

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I recently came across a table from a book I forgot what it was but it had a summary of methods for solving linear systems using PLU vs QR vs SVD vs Cholesky in terms of flop counts, I am not sure if it was Treften or Golub. I hope someone can direct me to a source.